# Separating a product of odd and even function

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this integration $\int f(x)g(x)dx$ where f(x) is odd and g(x) is even. Can I separate the integrals like

$\int f(x)dx  \int g(x)dx$. Note that the range of integration is from -infinity to infinity. So the integral will be zero definitely.

Comment: $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=x^2$.

Comment: As you said: Since the product is odd, the integral is 0, the second integral is also 0, since $f$ is odd. If the range would not be $(-\infty,\infty)$ or some symmetric set $A=-A$, I don't see any reason for the integrals to be equal. Remember the product rule? $(fg)'=f'g+g'f\neq f'g'$

Comment: So $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\,dx=0$?

Comment: @Michael Yes, for it is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left[\frac{x^2}2\right]_{x=-n}^n = \frac{n^2}2-\frac{n^2}2 = 0$.

Comment: I wonder if that approach is legitimate, e.g., we would also have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [x^2/2]^{2n}_{x=-n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{4n^2}{2}-\frac{n^2}{2} \rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: @Rebecca You are right, both limites must exist independently.  So what about $\int_{-n}^{\sqrt{n^2+c}}x\,dx$ for any reel number $c$?